# Relations between Heat Equation and density of polynomials.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In my homework about **heat equation** the professor want me to prove the following:

> Let $S$ e a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that the restrictions of polynomials to $S$ is dense in $C(S)$ in the uniform norm.

I know this is a consequence of Stone–Weierstrass theorem. But, this questions might be **tricky**.

Is there some magic relation between the density of polynomials and the theory of the heat equation? A hint to see the magic would be appreciated.

Thanks!